# Grails: How to specify the default/root controller in taglib arguments?

Tags: grails, controller, taglib

Is it possible to specify the root controller when using the built in grails taglibs?

For example, is there some way of doing something similar to:

```
<g:submitToRemote controller="/" action="someAction" />
```

which results in call to **/someAction**?

controller="/", "null" and "" are all invalid. Not specifying the controller parameter means that the current controller is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maps to controller + action, not to urls. Urls are configured at `conf/UrlMapping.groovy`.

And if your controller `RootController` with action `someAction` is mapped there to url `/someAction` then `<g:submitToRemote controller="root" action="someAction"/>` will use url `/someAction` as target.